# Animating Text in Matplotlib Basemap

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I plotting a 2D array over matplotlib's basemap and animating it through time. I am having trouble however adding in a time counter. The animation starts at 0 UT and progresses through 23 UT before starting back over at 0UT. The animation works beautifully.

Here is my code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, addcyclic
import matplotlib.animation as animation

#load the netcdf file into a variable
mar120="C:/Users/WillEvo/Desktop/My Datasets To Share/SA120_Iono_Acc_WE.nc"

#grab the data into a new variable
fh=Dataset(mar120,mode="r")

#assign model variable contents to python variables
lons=fh.variables['lon'][:]
lats=fh.variables['lat'][:]
var1=fh.variables['NTD_UP'][:]

#specifying which time and elevation to map
ionst=var1[0,18,:,:]
details='(0UT, Z=2)'

#close the netCDF file
fh.close()

details='(0UT, Z=2)'

# get rid of white stripe on map
ionst, lons=addcyclic(ionst, lons)

#Setting figure attributes
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,12),facecolor='white')

#map settings
m=Basemap(llcrnrlon=-180, llcrnrlat=-87.5, urcrnrlon=180, urcrnrlat=87.5,rsphere=6467997, resolution='l', projection='cyl',area_thresh=10000, lat_0=0, lon_0=0)

#Creating 2d array of latitude and longitude
lon, lat=np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
xi, yi=m(lon, lat)

#plotting data onto basemap
cs=m.imshow(ionst, interpolation=None, alpha=.8)

#drawing grid lines
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,90.,30.),labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,30.), labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=10)

#drawing coast lines
m.drawcoastlines()

#color bar
cbar=m.colorbar(cs, location='bottom', pad="10%")
cbar.set_label(r"Ion Drag $(cm/s^2)$")

#Title Preferences
plt.title('Ion Drag at '+details, size=16)


#Function to update the plots data
def updateax1(j):
    cs.set_array(var1[j,18,:,:])
    return cs,

#Animate the plot
ani1=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updateax1, frames=range(24), interval=150, blit=True)

#showing the plot
plt.show()
```

I have tried setting figure text like this:

```
text=figtext(0,0,'sometext')
```

and then updating it in my update function like this:

```
def updateax1(j):
        text.set_text(str(j))
        cs.set_array(var1[j,18,:,:])
        return cs, text,
```

but this just causes the entire animation to stop. I have been trying to figure this out for weeks. Please lend me your genius for just a few seconds! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution however it could not be found anywhere explicitly. Just change the text instance from a figtext to a simple ax.text instance and the animation works perfectly.